# wkhtmltopdf hangs at 10% when executed via PHP but runs successfully via command line

Tags: php, apache, pdf, centos, wkhtmltopdf

I use phpwkhtmltopdf as described here [How do I get WKHTMLTOPDF to execute via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663814/how-do-i-get-wkhtmltopdf-to-execute-via-php)

to convert html to pdf

```
set_time_limit (0);

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf; 

$pdf = new Pdf; 

$pdf->addPage('<html><h1>PDF creation successfull</h1></html>');

$pdf->send('test.pdf');
  if (!$pdf->send('test.pdf')) {
          throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
      }
```

when i run this i get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not
>   create PDF: Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% ' in
>   /home/kpninfotech/public_html/pdfbin/convert.php:30 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /home/kpninfotech/public_html/pdfbin/convert.php on
>   line 30

I also tried to run exec command from php

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $cmd = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.kpninfotech.com test.pdf 2>&1";
    echo $t = exec($cmd);
    exit();
```

Here also i get the same error

> [> ] 0% [======> ] 10%

But the pdf conversion runs successfully when executed via ssh
[image]

But i couldn't execute via PHP, How can i execute it via PHP?

I have VPS server running centos 6.5, wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.1 (with patched qt)

Comment: Looks like your php user (apache / www / etc.) does not have write-permissions. You could change the ownership of the directory where you want to write to the php user.

Comment: The server could able to create other files without errors http://kpninfotech.com/pdfbin/test1.php, executing the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560373/php-create-file-for-download-without-saving-on-server

Comment: Temporarily,  change the permission of your file to 777 and see what happens.

Comment: This is definitely a problem with your PHP configuration, I got this resolved when I upgraded to a better VPS server. If you have WHM access go &  set this package to use unlimited resource. It may fix it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exaticly problem setting options *disable-javascript*.

Try this.

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf; 

$pdf = new Pdf(array('disable-javascript')); 

$pdf->addPage('<html><h1>PDF creation successfull</h1></html>');

$pdf->send('test.pdf');
if (!$pdf->send('test.pdf')) {
  throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
}
```